# Ubuntu 18.10 slow boot after upgrading from 18.04 LTS

Tags: boot, 18.10

I have updated from 18.04 LTS to 18.10 and when booting, Ubuntu freezes nearly 30 second. It opens total like 2 minutes. I have tried nearly everything but I didnt find a solution. I looked apport.log but nothing seems wrong. I really appreciate if you could help.

My Xorg.0.log

```
[    52.154] (**) Option "_source" "server/udev"
[    52.155] (II) event6  - HP WMI hotkeys: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard Switch
[    52.155] (II) event6  - HP WMI hotkeys: device is a keyboard
[    52.155] (II) event6  - HP WMI hotkeys: device is a switch device
[    52.155] (II) event6  - HP WMI hotkeys: device removed
[    52.156] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/virtual/input/input7/event6"
[    52.156] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "HP WMI hotkeys" (type: KEYBOARD, id 12)
[    52.156] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[    52.156] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "tr"
[    52.157] (II) event6  - HP WMI hotkeys: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard Switch
[    52.157] (II) event6  - HP WMI hotkeys: device is a keyboard
[    52.157] (II) event6  - HP WMI hotkeys: device is a switch device
[   306.859] (**) Option "fd" "22"
[   307.101] (II) event2  - Power Button: device removed
[   307.101] (**) Option "fd" "25"
[   307.101] (II) event1  - Power Button: device removed
[   307.101] (**) Option "fd" "26"
[   307.101] (II) event9  - HP Truevision HD: HP Truevision: device removed
[   307.101] (**) Option "fd" "27"
[   307.101] (II) event3  - AT Translated Set 2 keyboard: device removed
[   307.101] (**) Option "fd" "28"
[   307.101] (II) event4  - SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: device removed
[   307.101] (**) Option "fd" "29"
[   307.101] (II) event5  - HP Wireless hotkeys: device removed
[   307.101] (**) Option "fd" "30"
[   307.101] (II) event6  - HP WMI hotkeys: device removed
[   307.102] (II) UnloadModule: "libinput"
[   307.102] (II) systemd-logind: releasing fd for 13:70
[   307.124] (II) UnloadModule: "libinput"
[   307.124] (II) systemd-logind: releasing fd for 13:69
[   307.160] (II) UnloadModule: "libinput"
[   307.160] (II) systemd-logind: releasing fd for 13:68
[   307.200] (II) UnloadModule: "libinput"
[   307.200] (II) systemd-logind: releasing fd for 13:67
[   307.216] (II) UnloadModule: "libinput"
[   307.216] (II) systemd-logind: releasing fd for 13:73
[   307.256] (II) UnloadModule: "libinput"
[   307.256] (II) systemd-logind: releasing fd for 13:65
[   307.276] (II) UnloadModule: "libinput"
[   307.276] (II) systemd-logind: releasing fd for 13:66
[   307.423] (WW) xf86CloseConsole: KDSETMODE failed: Input/output error
[   307.423] (WW) xf86CloseConsole: VT_GETMODE failed: Input/output error
[   307.423] (WW) xf86CloseConsole: VT_ACTIVATE failed: Input/output error
[   307.428] (II) Server terminated successfully (0). Closing log file.
```

and I want to say that when I boot ubuntu with non-graphical interface (tty1), it opens normal boot time (about 50 second). In tty1 when i exit tty1 with
`sudo service gdm start`

It delays like 30 second. the problem might be about this but I don't know what it is.

Here is my systemd-analyze blame:

```
31.989s plymouth-quit-wait.service
13.739s udisks2.service
13.737s networkd-dispatcher.service
12.991s apport-autoreport.11.307s postfix@-.
10.601s preload.
10.480s ModemManager.
7.854s dev-sda6.device
7.359s networking.service
7.051s accounts-daemon.service
```

and so on.

My systemd-analyze critical-chain:

```
 graphical.target @59.612s
    └─multi-user.target @59.611s
      └─fetchmail.service @38.552s +107ms
        └─postfix.service @38.547s +2ms
          └─postfix@-.service @27.239s +11.307s
            └─network-online.target @27.227s
              └─network.target @27.130s
                └─networking.service @19.770s +7.359s
                  └─apparmor.service @16.702s +2.922s
                    └─local-fs.target @16.672s
                      └─run-user-1000.mount @38.508s
                        └─swap.target @12.240s
                          └─dev-disk-by\x2duuid-ea82a086\x2d632f\x2d4439\x2da022\x2d
                            └─dev-disk-by\x2duuid-ea82a086\x2d632f\x2d4439\x2da022\x
```

Comment: I have added systemd analyze blame. It might be start job timeout but i didn't find what is is.